# Is there an insertion order preserving Set that also implements List?

Tags: java, collections

I'm trying to find an implementation of `java.util.List` and `java.util.Set` at the same time in Java. I want this class to allow only unique elements (as `Set`) and preserve their order (like `List`). Does it exist in JDK 6?

It's important to have `List<T>#add(int, T)` so I can insert into a specific position.

Comment: Do you mean preserve their **insertion** order or some order defined by a `Comparator`? Also do you want the semantics of the `List` interface as well?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

[`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is sorted by element order; [`LinkedHashSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) retains insertion order. Hopefully one of those is what you were after.

You've specified that you want to be able to insert at an *arbitrary* location, I suspect you'll have to write your own - just create a class containing a `HashSet<T>` and an `ArrayList<T>`; when adding an item, check whether or not it's in the set before adding it to the list.

Alternatively Apache's commons-collections4 offers [`ListOrderedSet`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/set/ListOrderedSet.html) and [`SetUniqueList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/SetUniqueList.html), which behave similarly and should meet the given requirements.

Answer (score 30):

LinkedHashSet is the answer.

Iteration ordering and uniqueness.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: It doesn't implement `List` interface, see my changes to the question

Answer (score 12):

Do you means like `LinkedHashSet`?  This preserves the order of entry, but doesn't allow duplicates.

IMHO, its an unusual requirement but you can write a List without duplicates.

```
class SetList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        return !super.contains(t) && super.add(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, T element) {
        if (!super.contains(element)) super.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        boolean added = false;
        for (T t : c)
            added |= add(t);
        return added;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> c) {
        boolean added = false;
        for (T t : c)
            if (!super.contains(t)) {
                super.add(index++, t);
                added = true;
            }
        return added;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't implement `List` interface, see my changes to the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8185105/253468 looks better because it does not have `O(n)` insertion complexity, there's a tradeoff one has to consider between double storage and `O(log(n))` insert operation.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot implement `List` and `Set` at once without contract violation. See, for example, the [`Set.hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#hashCode()) contract:

> The hash code of a set is defined to be the sum of the hash codes of the elements in the set, where the hash code of a null element is defined to be zero.

On the other hand here's the contract of [`List.hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode()):

> The hash code of a list is defined to be the result of the following calculation:
>
> ```
> int hashCode = 1;
> for (E e : list)
>     hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
> ```

So it's impossible to implement single class which guarantees both contracts to be fulfilled. The same problem for `equals` implementation.

Answer (score 4):

If you won't limit yourself to JDK 6 you could use [Apache common collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) library which offers exact match for your need - [ListOrderedSet](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/set/ListOrderedSet.html). It's like `List` and `Set` combined together :)

Comment: minus the `List` interface

Answer (score 1):

Another option (minus the `List` interface requirement) is Guava's [`ImmutableSet`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html), which preserves insertion order. From [their wiki page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained#how):

> Except for sorted collections, **order is preserved from construction time.** For example,
>
> ```
> ImmutableSet.of("a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "b")
> ```
>
> will iterate over its elements in the order "a", "b", "c", "d".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I wrote my own. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40384506/264177). The `IndexedArraySet` extends `ArrayList` and implements `Set`, so it should support all the operations that you need. Note that inserting elements into locations in the middle of an `ArrayList` can be slow for big lists because all the following elements need to be moved over. My `IndexedArraySet` doesn't change that.