# Get unique values from ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list, set

I have an `ArrayList` with a number of records and one column contains gas names as CO2 CH4 SO2, etc. Now I want to retrieve different gas names(unique) only without repeatation from the `ArrayList`. How can it be done?

Comment: I will update the tags. This is a Java question and I believe it is unrelated to jsf and primefaces...

Answer (score 159):

You should use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). A `Set` is a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) that contains no duplicates.

If you have a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) that contains duplicates, you can get the unique entries like this:

```
List<String> gasList = // create list with duplicates...
Set<String> uniqueGas = new HashSet<String>(gasList);
System.out.println("Unique gas count: " + uniqueGas.size());
```

**NOTE**: This `HashSet` constructor identifies duplicates by invoking the elements' *equals()* methods.

Comment: that implies that 2 records are considered equals (in the sense of HashSet) if their names are equals.

Comment: @njzk2 - I figured that would be pretty obvious, but I guess I can edit to point it out explicitly...

Comment: I get an error while trying to implement the above code:  `java: no suitable constructor found for HashSet`. Any idea why this occurs?

Comment: If you want to retain an original order from the list see `LinkedHashSet` https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712770/32453

Answer (score 93):

## You can use [Java 8 Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Method [distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) is an *intermediate operation* that filters the stream and allows only distinct values (by default using the Object::equals method) to pass to the next operation.
I wrote an example below for your case,

```
// Create the list with duplicates.
List<String> listAll = Arrays.asList("CO2", "CH4", "SO2", "CO2", "CH4", "SO2", "CO2", "CH4", "SO2");

// Create a list with the distinct elements using stream.
List<String> listDistinct = listAll.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

// Display them to terminal using stream::collect with a build in Collector.
String collectAll = listAll.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
System.out.println(collectAll); //=> CO2, CH4, SO2, CO2, CH4 etc..
String collectDistinct = listDistinct.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
System.out.println(collectDistinct); //=> CO2, CH4, SO2
```

Comment: The heading shouts - "Use this answer!! Not the accepted one". And I must say, this is the way to go.

Comment: This answer is probably great for most uses, but in case you need the list to always be of distinct values, say at time of populating it for example, then I would rather be using a `Set` like the accepted answer. I might not even have a `List` in the first place

Answer (score 15):

I hope I understand your question correctly: assuming that the values are of type `String`, the most efficient way is probably to convert to a `HashSet` and iterate over it:

```
ArrayList<String> values = ... //Your values
HashSet<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>(values);
for (String value : uniqueValues) {
   ... //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's straightforward way without resorting to custom comparators or stuff like that:

```
Set<String> gasNames = new HashSet<String>();
List<YourRecord> records = ...;

for(YourRecord record : records) {
  gasNames.add(record.getGasName());
}

// now gasNames is a set of unique gas names, which you could operate on:
List<String> sortedGasses = new ArrayList<String>(gasNames);
Collections.sort(sortedGasses);
```

Note: Using `TreeSet` instead of `HashSet` would give directly sorted arraylist and above `Collections.sort` could be skipped, but `TreeSet` is otherwise less efficent, so it's often better, and rarely worse, to use `HashSet` even when sorting is needed.

Answer (score 7):

you can use this for making a list Unique

```
ArrayList<String> listWithDuplicateValues = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("first");
list.add("first");
list.add("second");

ArrayList uniqueList = (ArrayList) listWithDuplicateValues.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
ArrayList values = ... // your values
Set uniqueValues = new HashSet(values); //now unique
```

Comment: I am now getting the unique elements from the list but it is being sorted by itself.But i need the data not to be in sorted order.How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static List getUniqueValues(List input) {
      return new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(incoming));
    }
```

dont forget to implement your equals method first

Answer (score 2):

When I was doing the same query, I had hard time adjusting the solutions to my case, though all the previous answers have good insights.

Here is a solution when one has to acquire a list of unique objects, NOT strings. 
Let's say, one has a list of Record object. `Record` class has only properties of type `String`, NO property of type `int`. 
Here implementing `hashCode()` becomes difficult as `hashCode()` needs to return an `int`.

The following is a sample `Record` Class.

```
public class Record{

    String employeeName;
    String employeeGroup;

    Record(String name, String group){  
        employeeName= name;
        employeeGroup = group;    
    }
    public String getEmployeeName(){
        return employeeName;
    }
    public String getEmployeeGroup(){
        return employeeGroup;
    }

  @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
         if(o instanceof Record){
            if (((Record) o).employeeGroup.equals(employeeGroup) &&
                  ((Record) o).employeeName.equals(employeeName)){
                return true;
            }
         }
         return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { //this should return a unique code
        int hash = 3; //this could be anything, but I would chose a prime(e.g. 5, 7, 11 )
        //again, the multiplier could be anything like 59,79,89, any prime
        hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.employeeGroup); 
        return hash;
    }
```

As suggested earlier by others, the class needs to override both the `equals()` and the `hashCode()` method to be able to use `HashSet`.

Now, let's say, the list of Records is `allRecord`(`List<Record> allRecord`).

```
Set<Record> distinctRecords = new HashSet<>();

for(Record rc: allRecord){
    distinctRecords.add(rc);
}
```

This will only add the distinct Records to the Hashset, distinctRecords.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of a some kind of object (bean) you can do this:

```
List<aBean> gasList = createDuplicateGasBeans();
Set<aBean> uniqueGas = new HashSet<aBean>(gasList);
```

like said Mathias Schwarz above, but you have to provide your aBean with the methods `hashCode()` and `equals(Object obj)` that can be done easily in Eclipse by dedicated menu '`Generate hashCode() and equals()`' (while in the bean Class).
Set will evaluate the overridden methods to discriminate equals objects.