# C# Distinct Extension Method in Java

Tags: c#, java, distinct

I am trying to implement the following `C#` code in `Java`:

```
List<org.joda.time.DateTime> times;
...
foreach (var time in times.OrderBy(d = > d).Distinct())
...
```

I'm using `Collections.sort()` to sort `times`, but what's the best way to implement the `Distinct()` method?

Comment: Possible duplication of [Get unique values from arraylist in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429119/get-unique-values-from-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

With new Java 8 syntax the code could look something like this:

```
times.stream()
    .sorted((d1, d2) -> d1.compareTo(d2)) // or just sorted() for default algorithm
    .distinct()
    .forEach(d -> System.out.println(d));
```