# Create a map of another map

Tags: java

I have a Map that looks like this:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();
```

Lets say the contents of the map looks like this:

```
one, [-55, -55, -54, -54, -55, -54, -54, -54, -54, -55]
two, [-61, -61, -61, -61, -60, -61, -60, -61, -60, -60]
three, [-69, -69, -68, -68, -68, -69, -70, -68, -69, -69]
```

I have created a method called "addRandomValuesToList" that looks at a list of integers called input, takes 4 values and puts them into another list called randomValues.

```
public static List<Integer> addRandomValuesToList(List<Integer> input) 
{
    List<Integer> randomValues = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    return randomValues 
}
```

I want to use the addRandomValuesToList method on all the list I have in the map so I get for example:

```
one, [-54, -54, -54, -54]
two, [-61, -61, -61, -61,]
three, [-69 -69, -70, -68]
```

I have a hard time doing this. I tried something like:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> test = new TreeMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     newList = addRandomValuesToList(entry.getValue());
     test.put(entry.getKey(), newList);
}
```

This causes some lists in the test map to be completely empty. Am I doing something wrong or is my approach wrong?

Comment: Share the code inside `addRandomValuesToList()`

Comment: What are you doing in method `addRandomValuesToList`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get unique values from arraylist in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429119/get-unique-values-from-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should declare the variable as local as possible. (It will store memory only once in a loop.)

Also the Map.Entry is backed by the internal data of the map. So it has a method `setValue`, though ofcourse not `setKey`.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> test = new TreeMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     List<Integer> newList = addRandomValuesToList(entry.getValue());
     entry.setValue(newList);
}
```

Also the `getValue` list is internal data from the map, is backed by the map. One could do:

```
entry.getValue().add(42);
```

`addRandomValuesToList`: if it indeed *modifies* the passed entry value, the method can be void, no need to do something with the result.

About the error I am uncertain. Every list in the map, must be a new instance (`new ArrayList<>()` or such).