# Collection that will maintain insertion order and no duplicates

Tags: java, collections

In Java collection which collection will doesn't allow duplicates and which also preserve insertion order of data?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712469/any-implementation-of-ordered-set-in-java

Comment: LinkedHashSet ............

Comment: Why is this marked as a duplicate of 'Is there an insertion order preserving set in Java?' This is not a duplicate of that, that question asks about Sets and Lists; this question is about all collections.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
LinkedHashSet
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

> This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a
>   doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked
>   list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which
>   elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)

Answer (score 22):

`LinkedHashSet` does both of them

```
Set set = new LinkedHashSet();
```

Comment: A `HashSet` won't preserve the order of insertion.

Comment: [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) doesn't preserve insertion order.

Comment: Yes, sorry got too excited :)

Comment: Unfortunately your edit did not register as an edit so I cannot retract my downvote. You might want to consider a more substantial edit of your answer.

Answer (score 10):

A [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) should fit the bill.

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with **predictable iteration order**. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, **which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)**.

Answer (score 6):

You can check [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) for this purpose.

A [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) will not allow duplicate values. And [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) will preserve insertion order.

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the
>   order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order).
>   Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted
>   into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is
>   invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the
>   invocation.)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
public class LinkedHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E>
```

Basically Set won't allow duplicates and

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Answer (score 2):

You want an ordered set, which is implemented by [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).