# What does it mean by "Insertion Order is preserved in Collections"?

Tags: java, collections

If we want to represent a group of individual objects where duplicates are allowed and insertion order is preserved, then we should go for List.

Here, what does insertion order refers to?

Comment: The order in which elements are added to the list is the order in which they are retrieved from the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collection that will maintain insertion order and no duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480529/collection-that-will-maintain-insertion-order-and-no-duplicates)

Comment: Say you're trying to represent a line-up in a store. You want to make sure that you remember what order customers entered the line, so they can be served in that order. In this scenario you would need a collection where insertion order is preserved.

Comment: The order you inserted the elements can be retrieved by iterating over the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insertion Order means the order in which we are inserting the data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("alpha");
    list.add("beta");
    list.add("gamma");

    for (String string : list) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

**Output :**
alpha
beta
gamma

Insertion order is maintained.

> If you want the original insertion order there are the Linked`XXX`
>   classes, which maintain an additional linked list in insertion order.
>   Most of the time you don't care, so you use a Hash`XXX`, or  if you want a natural order, so you use Tree`XXX`.

Answer (score 9):

Insertion order refers to **the order in which you are adding elements to the data structure (i.e., a collection like `List`, `Set`, `Map`, etc..)**.

For example, a `List` object maintains the order in which you are adding elements, whereas a `Set` object doesn't maintain the order of the elements in which they are inserted.

First, take a `List` object and add elements:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("1Z");
list.add("2Y");
list.add("3X");
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output (i.e., objects inside `List`):  [1Z, 2Y, 3X]  (order same as the insertion)**

Now, take a `Set` object:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("1Z");
set.add("2Y");
set.add("3X");
System.out.println(set);
```

**Output (i.e., objects inside `Set`): [3X, 2Y, 1Z] (order disturbed)**

Answer (score 8):

The insertion order is the order used to add the elements in the collection.

[Iteration order for above implementations](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65):

- HashSet - undefined.
- HashMap - undefined
- LinkedHashSet - insertion order
- LinkedHashMap - insertion order of keys (by default), or
  'access order'
- ArrayList - insertion order.
- LinkedList - insertion order.
- TreeSet - ascending order, according to Comparable /
  Comparator.

There are collection the could preserve the insertion order when you add an element, others cannot. Please refer at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480529/collection-that-will-maintain-insertion-order-and-no-duplicates)