# How to Union List<Date> list1 and List<Date> list2 in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, union

```
  public class ArrayOfArrayList {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Date> dateList1 = new ArrayList<Date>();
    List<Date> dateList2 = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Date d1 = new Date();
        cal.setTime(d1);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
        dateList1.add(cal.getTime());
    }
    System.out.println("   *************** Date List 1st ****************");
    for(Date date1 : dateList1) {
        System.out.println("1stList"+date1);
    }
    System.out.println("   *************** Date List 1st ****************");

    for(int i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
        Date d2 = new Date();
        cal.setTime(d2);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
        dateList2.add(cal.getTime());
    }
    System.out.println("   *************** Date List 2nd ****************");
    for(Date date2 : dateList2) {
        System.out.println("2ndList"+date2);
    }
    System.out.println("   *************** Date List 2nd ****************");

    System.out.println("   *********** Start Union Dates ************");
    List<Date> finalList = union(dateList1,dateList2);
    Collections.sort(finalList);
    System.out.println("\n   ********* After Union Dates ***********");
    for(Date fDate : finalList) {
        System.out.println(fDate);
    }
    System.out.println("\n ********* After Union Dates **********");    
}

private static  List<Date> union(List<Date> dateList1, List<Date> dateList2)       {
    HashSet<Date> dateSet = new HashSet<Date>();
    dateSet.addAll(dateList1);
    dateSet.addAll(dateList2);
    List<Date> finalDateList = new ArrayList<Date>(dateSet);
    return finalDateList;
}}
```

with Union Method still i am getting Duplicate Dates could you anyone help me to fix this issue some time answer comes correct but sometime duplicate still present please guide me

O/P

```
     *************** Date List 1st ****************
    1stListFri Oct 21 00:38:53 IST 2016
    1stListSat Oct 22 00:38:53 IST 2016
    1stListSun Oct 23 00:38:53 IST 2016
    1stListMon Oct 24 00:38:53 IST 2016
    1stListTue Oct 25 00:38:53 IST 2016
    *************** Date List 1st ****************
    *************** Date List 2nd ****************
    2ndListSun Oct 23 00:38:53 IST 2016
    2ndListMon Oct 24 00:38:53 IST 2016
    2ndListTue Oct 25 00:38:53 IST 2016
    2ndListWed Oct 26 00:38:53 IST 2016
    2ndListThu Oct 27 00:38:53 IST 2016
    2ndListFri Oct 28 00:38:53 IST 2016
    *************** Date List 2nd ****************
    *************** Start Union Dates ****************

    *************** After Union Dates ****************
         Fri Oct 21 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Sat Oct 22 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Sun Oct 23 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Sun Oct 23 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Mon Oct 24 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Mon Oct 24 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Tue Oct 25 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Tue Oct 25 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Wed Oct 26 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Thu Oct 27 00:38:53 IST 2016
         Fri Oct 28 00:38:53 IST 2016

   *************** After Union Dates ****************
```

As you can see the Above Outputs still duplicate is present in the final list after Union of two dates

Comment: How about putting them in a `Set`?

Comment: @Kayaman - Did you read OP's code? That's exactly what `union()` is doing.

Comment: The dates likely differ in milliseconds. Set them to 0 and it should work. `timeInMillis - (timeInMillis % 1000)` should do the trick

Comment: @TedHopp I think the answer to that is obvious.

Comment: k5_ was faster :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
SortedSet<ZonedDateTime> union = 
    new TreeSet<>().addAll( zdtsA ).addAll( zdtsB ) ;
```

## Details

The [accepted Answer by GhostCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40162921/642706) is correct. The poorly designed `toString` method masked the fractional second that made each seemingly-duplicate value actually distinct.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` are poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. They are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Among the many reasons to replace those old classes is the poor choice of behavior of the `toString` method. Not only does it dynamically apply a time zone to a value that is actually in UTC, it also masks the fractional second. That hiding of the fractional second is your core problem here as you did not realize the values were identical to the second but not identical in the fraction.

## java.time

The equivalent of [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

Fortunately, the implementation of the `toString` methods in the java.time classes such as `Instant` do *not* hide the fractional second. By default the fractional second, if any, is displayed in groups of 3 digits as needed for the value. So you will see zero, three, six, or nine digits of fractional second when generating a String to represent the date-time value.

### `Instant`

To convert to/from java.time, look to new methods added on the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

#### Truncate

You can [truncate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation) the fractional second if desired. You can truncate to any granularity you want, as defined in a [`TemporalUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) such as those implemented in [`ChronoUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) such as whole seconds, minutes, hours, etc.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

If you want to increment by 24-hour increments, call the [`plus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method on `Instant`.

```
Instant dayLater = instant.plus( 1 , ChronoUnit.DAYS );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to increment by days that respect anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) rather than simply adding 24-hour increments, apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

By the way, if you only cared about date and not time-of-day, extract a `LocalDate` with a call to `toLocalDate`.

Increment by days, and collect.

```
int count = 5 ;
List<ZonedDateTime> datesA = new ArraySet<>( count );
for( int i = 1 , i <= count , i++ ) {
    datesA.add( zdt );
    // Prepare for next loop.
    zdt = zdt.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

### `SortedSet`

A [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and so eliminates duplicates. A [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is also a [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (see [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/sorted-set.html)) and so keeps the values sorted, in this case sorted in chronological order. To union while eliminating duplicates, add all elements of both [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) objects to a `SortedSet` like `TreeSet`.

```
SortedSet<ZonedDateTime> union = new TreeSet<>();
union.addAll( datesA );
union.addAll( datesB );
```

You can make a `List` from the `SortedSet` similar to code seen in the Question. The SortedSet iterator traverses the set in ascending element order, so the resulting `List` will be in chronological order.

```
List<ZonedDateTime> finalDateList = new ArrayList<>(dateSet);
```

For more discussion of `SortedSet`, see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8712469/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8725387/642706), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1463284/642706).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is here; as you do:

```
dateList1.add(cal.getTime());
```

You assume that two dates are *equal* when their printout (like above) is equal. But that is not true! You simply forgot that "dates" include **milli seconds**, too. If you change your formatting to include that information, you will find that your dates might have same hours:minutes:seconds ... but all *different* milli second values!

Thus the Set does **not** see duplicated entries; it just sees all different objects!

So, in order to make your union work, you have to "normalize" those parts within a Date that you want to ignore. Two ways there:

1. As mentioned in the comments, just push "0" for milliseconds into all the created Date objects!
2. You could be using a TreeSet and a *custom* Comparator; and that Comparator can ensue that Dates that are only different on milliseconds are showing up as equal. But that isn't really a great approach, as you have no control which of your Dates will "survive" then.

Comment: The use of the TreeSet, along with the 0'ing of milliseconds would solve the whole problem, including the sorting into ascending order. Good call @GhostCat

Answer (score -1):

Use set as filter, not as storage:

```
    HashSet<String> dateSet = new HashSet<String>();
    return Stream.concat(dateList1.stream(), dateList2.stream())
            .filter(d -> dateSet.add(d.toString()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I've downvoted this because it uses some rather non-intuitive techniques here. It's aggregating to a set anyway, but then using the result of aggregation as a filter - that's a filter with an odd side-effect. I think this code would be hard to understand in real life. You may as well just collect the two lists to a set and then convert that set back to a list. It also doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: I agree with Ashley. Another person might look at this code for an hour, not understanding the point of turning the Date into a String so that "equal" Dates can be filtered out.