# looking for a special java collection

Tags: java

Is there a java collection that only allow unique object in and with a get (index i) method ?

i firstly think of a treeSet but there is no get methods in ...
what i want be able to :

```java
// replace object with any class that implement the right things to make it work
Collection<Object> collection = dunno<Object>();
Object o = new Object()
Object o2 = new Object()

collection.add(o)
collection.add(o)

collection.size() // should get 1
collection.get(0) // should return o

// let's suppose that o2 is lower than o (if the collection doesn't sort the way i want i can change it anyway)

collection.add(o2)
collection.get(0) // should return o2
```

so basicly like a treeSet but with a get methods does anyone know something like that ?

Comment: You could always use `contains` before adding to a `List` if you need to

Comment: yes it could be a good idea is using contain and adding to a list as fast as adding to a treeSet especially for some large set ? i could easly manupulate over a thousand of element ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any implementation of Ordered Set in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712469/any-implementation-of-ordered-set-in-java)

Comment: The answers in the question @SomeDude linked to suggests LinkedHashSet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such collection in the in the standard library, and I am also not aware of something like that in other widespread libraries like guava or apache commons.

Thus the answer is: you will have to implement your own collection for that. A straight forward solution would use a set and a list to provide the required interface, which will work but obviously increase the memory footprint to a certain degree.

Answer (score 0):

override `equals` and `hashcode` in ur custom class
use `Arraylist` and u can check `list.contains` before adding to remove duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) maintains the order of insertion while maintaining also the uniqueness of the items inserted.

Although it doesn’t have a dedicated get(i) method you can implement one by just iterating through the set.

You will pay for the performance of get() though.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `LinkedHashSet`.
This collection does only accept unique objects and keeps track of the order

Comment: It doesn't have indices though, which is what the Galyfray wants