# Remove repetitive string from sentence in java

Tags: java, string, repeat

I am working on java code in which I want to remove repetitive words. Following code works fine to remove them if I get space in any word for example:
`1298 Anthony 1298 Anthony`, it will make it like:
`1298 Anthony`

But for any other special character like:
`1298 Anthony.ef 1298 Anthony.ef`, it will show it like:
`ef. 1298 Anthony`.

My method is given below, I want to make it work for every special character, specially for : coma(,) , fullstop(.), dash(-), underscore(_). Please help me in this problem.

```
public static void removeString(){

    String name1 = "1298 Anthony.ef 1298 Anthony.ef";

    String[] strArr = name1.split(" ");
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(strArr));

    String[] result = new String[set.size()];
    set.toArray(result);
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        String string = result[i];
        if(i==result.length-1){
            res.append(string);
        }
        else{
            res.append(string).append(" ");
        }

    }
    System.out.println(res.toString());
    String abc = res.toString();
}
```

Comment: Well, I don't know if I understand you correctly, but you might try something like **name1.split("\\s|\\.|,|\\-")**

Comment: I have executed your code and it yielded `1298 Anthony.ef`. Is this not what you are after?

Comment: Rather **name1.split((\\s|\p{Punct})+)** See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html for different character classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're splitting `name1` around spaces. You can try to split `name1` around [any non-word character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html):

```
names.split("\\W+");
```

Method [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) accepts regex as argument. To quote from the docs:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

`name1.split(" ");` splits string around single space and returns array: `[1298, Anthony.ef, 1298, Anthony.ef]`

`names.split("\\W+");` splits string around any non-word character (comma, dot, dash, etc.) and returns array: `[1298, Anthony, ef, 1298, Anthony, ef]`
As you can see in this case it was able to split `Anthony.ef` into separate strings.

**UPDATE:** If you want to preserve word's order in the original string you might want to use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`. For example:

```
public static void removeString(){

    String name1 = "1298 Anthony.ef 1298 Anthony.ef";

    String[] strArr = name1.split("\\W+");
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(strArr));

    String[] result = new String[set.size()];
    set.toArray(result);
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        String string = result[i];
        if(i==result.length-1){
            res.append(string);
        }
        else{
            res.append(string).append(" ");
        }

    }
    System.out.println(res.toString());
    String abc = res.toString();
}
```

Check out this question: [Is there an insertion order preserving Set that also implements List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185090/is-there-an-insertion-order-preserving-set-in-java)

Comment: thanks for your reply here. Can you please explain me little bit more here, i exactly didn't get your point.

Comment: It's just "Anthony.ef" will be split into "Anthony" and "ef"

Comment: @Android_Zapier see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: @Android_Zapier I have included additional explanations. Please refer to tutorial/documentation links provided in the answer.

Comment: @defaultlocale thanks for your answer here. It works and removes Dot from the string. But the problem is that it is showing the word in reverse direction like: ef Argentina, please help me out here

Comment: @Android_Zapier In what order do you want words to appear? If you want to preserve the order in the original string you might want to use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185090/is-there-an-insertion-order-preserving-set-in-java

Comment: @defaultlocale thanks for your reply. Can you please put some code snippet here according to my condition, it will help me a lot in this regard.

Comment: @defaultlocale kindly help me out here with code snippet according to my condition. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @defaultlocale thank you so much dear, it works perfectly as you say here. Thanks.....!!!